# Replace a part of statement with another in whole source code

Tags: linux, vim, sed

I am trying to find the whole source code for occurrences of, say, "MY_NAME" and want to replace it with, say, "YOUR_NAME". I already know the files and the line numbers where they occur and i want to make a patch for the same so that anyone running the patch can do the same. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you NEED to use what you know about line numbers? The script would be much simpler to write if you just let it look for MY_NAME and replace it with YOU_NAME wherever it occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by console. Just use *find* to locate destination files, and then you can declare what you want to replace with what sentence. In example:

```
find -name '*' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g'
```

Comment: `-name` is unnecessary/redundant if you use an argument of `'*'` - just do `find | xargs ...` instead. But you might want to add `-type f` so you only look at files and not directories, symlinks, sockets, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do a sed command, and then generate a patch.

```
sed -e '12s/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g;32s/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g' file > file2
```

This will replace MY_NAME with YOUR_NAME on lines 12 and 32, and save the output into file2.

You can also generate a sed script if there are many changes:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

12s/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g
32s/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g
```

Then, for applying to many files, you should use `find`:

```
find -type f '(' -iname "*.c" -or -iname "*.h" ')' -exec "./script.sed" '{}' \;
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: And If he wants to replace all the occurrences in the file simply avoid specifying the line number.

Comment: what is i want to add another like to all the touched files? as in the whole source code has a lot of files..the script will be applicable for just one file right?

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho: So i add this find line to my script in the beginning? Also, all the files dont have those occurrences at the same line numbers. Some files have 15-20 occurrences and mostly all the files have the occurrences at different line numbers. How do i proceed then? :)

Comment: You can execute the `find` command in the shell (or place in a bash script). That command will search for all `.c` and `.h` files and execute the sed script (supposing it's called `script.sed`). In the case the lines on the files are different, you can either use *SinnerShanky*'s suggestion of replacing all occurrances (removing the line number from the command: `s/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g`), or if all files have the lines in the same range of lines, you can specify that with the starting line, followed by a comma, then the ending line: `10,250s/MY_NAME/YOUR_NAME/g` (range of lines 10-250).

Comment: Okay cool. Now there's just one more thing. What if in all those files i want to add a line of code in the starting?

Comment: By "starting" you mean before the first line? You can use the `i` insert command, and prefix it with the first line as the address: `1i\<new-line>New first line`, will insert the line "New first line" at the start of the file. Notice that you have to add a backslash followed by a newline character after the `i`. Another way is to use a substitute command, also prefixed with the first line address: `1s/^/This is appended at the start of the first line/`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command diff to create a patch-file that can then be distributed and applied with the patch-command.

`man diff` Will give you a lot of information on the process.